# exchange powershell : get-user has no Description property?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2007

When I run `get-user|get-member` in powershell with the exchange add-in I noticed there is no description property.

Does anyone know if it has been renamed to something else or another way of accessing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't looking to change the description this should work:

```
[PS] C:\>$ANR = "testuser@example.com"
[PS] C:\>$foo = [adsi]("LDAP://" + (get-user $ANR).DistinguishedName)
[PS] C:\>$foo.description
My Description
```

If you are wanting to edit, you will need to get further into System.DirectoryServices & look at how to write objects back to AD.  It would likely be simpler to use quest of another package that does some wrapping.  If you want to roll your own there are gobs of blogs on AD programming in Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange itself provides minimal interaction with AD - essentially, it gives you some AD stuff because AD and Exchange are so connected, but it doesn't try to expose all of AD's functionality.

Check out quest.com/powershell; that is an add-in library (it's free), and it has a cmdlet called Get-QADUser which will get you what you need - somewhat more easily, and in a more PowerShell-ish fashion, than using ADSI (which is also completely legit for what you're after).

Comment: But is it "really" even adsi if the object returned is a DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry?  All things become fuzzy, all edges blurred :)

Answer (score 0):

get-user? do you mean get-qaduser from the quest cmdlet suite?

if so, I believe not all properties are retrieved by default. There's an -Include parameter that lets you specify additional properties to retrieve from AD, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

It works on the console; however in the CSV file, it keeps appending

System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection

to the end of each line instead of the value
When I run it on the prompt by typing out the distinguishedname, the ldap query works..

> $tmp =adsi
>   $tmp.description
>   bill

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

solved it..  its just $tmp.description.value